# AutoIt ControlCommand is not working as expected

Tags: windows, winapi, autoit

I'm using AutoIt to try and make a little hotkey application to work with [Windows Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Journal) so I can quickly select different colors.

It seems I'm very close and yet very far to getting the desired result. I've used the AutoIt tool to find the CommandID of the toolbar and the ID of the colors. Here is my code:

```
    ControlCommand("[CLASS:JournalApp]","",113,"SendCommandID", 40178)
```

My problem is that the color will not be selected. It will be selected to the degree that the color will have the "selection" brackets around it, but the color that I draw with will still be the last color I've selected.

So I tried messing around and found that this code:

```
    ControlCommand("[CLASS:JournalApp]","",113,"Check","")
```

It will indeed select the color, but it will only select the light blue color. I don't know why, but that is the color that is always being selected. I have not found a way to combine the selecting ability of **"SendCommandID"** with the checking ability of **"Check"**

Also, it is a ToolbarWin32 Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

**Here's what I've learned:**

```
ControlCommand("[CLASS:JournalApp]","",113,"Check","")
```

Has a serious weakness in that it there is no way to specify which button will be checked. At first it seemed to be random, but after a while of playing around I noticed that it did it at a specific coordinate relative to the client window. Why? I have no idea. But at least it's not random.

```
ControlCommand("[CLASS:JournalApp]","",113,"SendCommandID", 40178)
```

Has a weakness in that, while on the surface it appears to have successfully clicked the button. The button's function is not actually executed. For my specific circumstance, the color of the pen did not change after I used this, though it appeared to click on the button.

**Here's my solution(s):**

I looked around and found that AutoIt has a library specifically for dealing with ToolBarWin32 Classes. This is the library from `GuiToolbar.au3`. With this I found that I was able to do a few things. One, was that I could send clicks to the buttons and change the state of the buttons even. I found that changing the state of the buttons did nothing in relation to triggering an event and the clicking worked, but it had the weakness that it caused the mouse to flinch. This did not work because my pen was near my tablet as that has priority of mouse movement. So I had to raise my pen away from my tablet in order to use the hotkeys--not very convenient. Here was my code for that solution:

```
if WinActive("[CLASS:JournalApp]") Then
    WinActivate("[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:2]", "")
    $cmdId = "401"&$hotKeys[$key-1+$shift]
    If $cmdId < 40172 or $cmdId > 40188 Then
        Return
    EndIf
    $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:JournalApp]", "", 113)
    _GUICtrlToolbar_ClickButton($hWnd, $cmdId)
EndIf
```

What I found after was that AutoIt's native `ControlClick()` was a lot more useful in that it didn't cause the mouse to flinch whatsoever. It triggered the mouseclick event directly. So that in combination with a nice command from the toolbar library made for a much cleaner solution. Here it is:

```
if WinActive("[CLASS:JournalApp]") Then
    WinActivate("[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:2]", "")
    $cmdId = "401"&$hotKeys[$key-1+$shift]
    If $cmdId < 40172 or $cmdId > 40188 Then
        Return
    EndIf
    ConsoleWrite($hotKeys[$key-1])
    $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:JournalApp]", "", 113)

    ;get the coords of the button and control send a click
    local $btnCoords= _GUICtrlToolbar_GetButtonRect($hWnd, $cmdId)

    ControlClick("[CLASS:JournalApp]", "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:2]","left",1,$btnCoords[0]+2,$btnCoords[1]+2)
EndIf
```